# Understanding Bayes' Theorem, or: Are all pluviophobes hermits?

Tags: bayesian, philosophical

Let $A$ be the event "I go out", $B$ be the event "It rains". Then Bayes' Theorem tells us that $$P[A|B] = \frac{P[B|A]P[A]}{P[B]}.$$

I think the weather doesn't care what I do, so $P[B|A]=P[B]$ and the equation simplifies to $$P[A|B]=P[A].$$ Suppose I really don't like getting wet, so $P[A|B]=0$. Then $P[A]=0$, and I'm a hermit. Can this be right?

Comment: These are *probability* statements.  Anthropomorphising the weather is not a reasonable way to think about them.  If *you* respond to weather conditions, then perforce your actions are related to the weather.

Comment: @whuber OK; so, in particular, I can choose not to go out when it's already raining; but I can't choose not to get caught in the rain, unless I'm totally risk-averse and therefore indeed a hermit, or can teleport home instantaneously when the rain starts. If neither of those is true then non-zero intrinsic probabilities $P[A],P[B]$ of me going out and of it raining imply a non-zero probability $P[A|B]$ of me being out while it's raining. Sound right?

Comment: I don't see how any of that follows logically--I'm probably not understanding.  Bayes' theorem is mathematical fact.  If you wish to reason about events using concepts of probability, then you have no choice concerning how those probabilities combine, just as you have no choice concerning how to combine the counts of your apples and oranges when enumerating fruits: you must add them.  It's difficult to see where this is going or how a discussion of getting wet when it rains might be germane to statistics and machine learning.

Comment: @whuber I think I've got what I needed. Thanks for the nudge. I suspect we might have different ideas of how a "mathematical fact" relates to physical reality, and that's not a point we need to thrash out here. Briefly, I think what puzzled me has to do with the relation of conjunctions of events to temporal sequencing and causation.

Comment: The issue seems to be your conflation of *causal* dependence (event A is in some sense *causing* event B, $A\to B$) and stochastic dependence  ($P(B|A)\neq P(B)$). It might happen that B causes A ($B\to A$) or that some other event M is causally related to both ($A\leftarrow M \to B$), for example, and in either case you could then have $P(B|A)\neq P(B)$. Stochastic dependence is not causal (or as the common saying has it, *correlation is not causation*, interpreting correlation in the broader sense of association)

Comment: @Glen_b Isn't significant correlation causation upto direction? That is, significant correlation implies one of $A\rightarrow B;\;B\rightarrow A;\;M\rightarrow A,B$. If my response to rain affects the probability that it's raining when I'm outside, this relationship is causal, in the sense I described above, no?

Comment: When I said "the issue" I was referring directly to this "the weather doesn't care what I do, so P[B|A]=P[B]". The reasoning is flawed, and I suspect the reason is related to what I mention above.